# Fingertip Detection in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, computer-vision, aforge

I'm just wondering about how the fingertips of a hand gesture are detected.

I am using this finger counts for finger spelling. More specifically, I am working on C# with [AFORGE.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) and want to use convex-hull algorithm for it. Everything I can find is done in the `OPENCV` platform.

Please suggest a method of finding the fingertip count in C#, and if possible without using `OPENCV` platform.

Comment: Why not ask on the AFORGE forum? http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/

Comment: Mike, Obviously, because it is closed  
http://www.aforgenet.com/news/2012.04.01.end_of_free_public_support.html

Comment: Even worse, why use a closed project at all? Is there a forked continuation?

Comment: Thanks @Grigory, i do not even noticed that AFORGE public support is already closed. After way any ideas on what i am doing??

Comment: I think you're doing this the wrong way: This is a very specialized problem and AFORGE is a niche-framework, the chances to find someone who can answer both the algorithm question *and* the specific implementation problems are very slim. Better ask a general question on how to detect fingertips (include sample images!) using OpenCV, Matlab or whatever platform. Then try to port that to AFORGE, and ask *specific* questions about AFORGE (like "how do I reproduce Matlab's `imremap` command"?) when you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

With [Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kinect/info) you can use [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) or the [Kinect for Windows SDK](http://kinectforwindows.org) using [this hack](http://www.csail.mit.edu/node/1392) by CSAIL.